# Centering div elements horizontally and vertically in a container while maintaining its position

Tags: html, css

```css
.container{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
}
.outer{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  border:5px solid gold;
}
.inner{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  border:5px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to stack the inner and outer div directly ontop each other,so the inner div would be at the center of the outer div, while centering the parent div fixed horizontally and vertically on the webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is useful for centering.

```css
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container, .outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.outer{
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 5px solid gold;
}
.inner{
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 5px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I try to fix the inner div position in the center, while the parent div keeps both vertical and horizontal center!

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 5px solid gold;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 5px solid gold;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```